# Error al conectar GCP App Engine a GCP SQL

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Estoy tratando de hacer el despliegue de una aplicación Flask en el App Engine, pero me da este error de conexión a base de datos:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003,
> "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 111] Connection
> refused)")

La conexión la estoy haciendo de esta manera:

```
databaseUri = 'mysql+pymysql://user:pass@/database?unix_socket=/cloudsql/connection_name'
```

También ya tengo activada la API de **Administrador de Cloud SQL** como dice en la documentación, pero no logro que funcione.

Alguien tiene alguna idea de que es lo que me falta configurar o que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Llevo 2 días en esto y no logro solucionarlo, gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 2):

Logré resolverlo.

Publico la solución por si es útil para alguien.

Aún no se por qué, pero al ejecutar el comando para desplegar la aplicación en el App Engine:

```
gcloud app deploy
```

Se esta utilizando por defecto la cuenta de servicio del Compute Engine en lugar de la del App Engine, solo tuve que ejecutar el comando especificando que se utilizara la cuenta de servicio del App Engine:

```
gcloud app deploy --service-account=SERVICE_ACCOUNT
```

Espero que esto sea útil para algún otro novato como yo con GCP.